# How to disable activation specification on the IBM websphere

Tags: java, jms, websphere, websphere-7, websphere-8

we have the J2EE application that is deployed on several profiles. For some strange reason, we want that processing of the JMS messages, by message-driven beans was on the one certain profile.

So we want to disable the activation specification on the other profiles.

Just deletion the activation specification not suites, because without it our application is not starting, with some initial context factory exceptions

Stop and resume solution not really suites, because every time after the server restart the activation specification is active again and one day, somebody will forget to switch it off.

So if there is a way completely disable the activation specification on the IBM websphere server, with the working application? Or any other ideas how to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling MQ at the server level? I found a few options in the infocenter for 8.5.

1. To disable WebSphere MQ functionality in a WebSphere Application Server client process, specify the custom property com.ibm.ejs.jms.disableWMQSupport=true.
2. Using the administrative console, select the Disable WebSphere MQ check box on the required WebSphere MQ messaging provider panel.
3. Use the manageWMQ administrative command with the disableWMQ flag

[Disable WebSphere MQ](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5////////com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tmm_wmq_disable.html?lang=en)

Comment: Thank, unfortunately with the switched off MQ support, the application is not started(

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via wsadmin script.

Query endpoints to find name of endpoint for your bean:

```
AdminControl.queryNames('*:type=J2CMessageEndpoint,*')
```

pause endpoint:

```
objectName=AdminControl.queryNames('*:name=JMSMDB_MessageEndpoint,*') 
AdminControl.invoke(objectName, 'pause')
```

to start it again issue:

```
objectName=AdminControl.queryNames('*:name=JMSMDB_MessageEndpoint,*') 
AdminControl.invoke(objectName, 'resume')
```

For more details see - [Managing the message endpoint lifecycle using wsadmin scripting](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/txml_7msgend.html?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

The wsadmin script is probably what you wanted.  But you can also do this via the Admin Console.  Navigate to the enterprise application list and select the link for your application.  If your application has an MDB component, the application panel should have a **Runtime** tab.  Select this tab to see a link for message listeners.  Click this link to see a list of MDBs that you can pause and resume.

Comment: I believe that he wanted to stop active specs for other legs of the cluster, but have only one leg running, and console, I think, will stop all. So from my point of view wsadmin is only way.